# How to get C# library file in output directory?

Tags: c#, buildaction

I have a solution with a few projects:

1. library.dll with `something.json`
2. webapp.dll
3. winapp.exe

2 and 3 depend on 1, not on eachother.

I would like copy `something.json` to the bin directory of winapp.exe

However setting the properties to `Content` and `Copy always` doesn't do what I expected.

[image]

Comment: Is it copied in the `library.dll` output dir ?

Comment: @limserhane Yes it does, however library.dll itself also is present in winapp's bin as expected. Just not `something.json`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Post-build event command line of your `winapp.exe` for instruct to copy that file inside your target dir

something like this

```
xcopy /Y  $your path of something.json $(TargetDir).
```

Change `your path of something.json` to your actual path.

Remember that you have a set of usefull link

- (TargetDir) = Where your project is going to be compiled
- (SolutionDir) = The solution path on your disk
- (ProjectDir) = The project path on your disk

Comment: @AliasgharAhmadpour remember that this is not a competition, any contribution is welcome ;) this answer gives a bit more explanations than yours, and since it has been accepted, he was right to write it.

Comment: Ok @limserhane. You are right. but this is not my mean.
So i'v deleted my comment

Answer (score 2):

You can use Build events.

Go to "Project properties -> Build events -> Post build events command line:"

And use command to copy any file

Read more about Build events on [Build events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2022)